# Incompatible types: Int and Article

Tags: android-recyclerview, types, incompatibility

I am developing news app I have implemented multipleview types in recyclerview adapter class but I am getting following error

> Incompatible types: Int and Article

below BBCSportAdapter class where I have implemented multipleview types

```
@Suppress("UNREACHABLE_CODE")
class BBCSportAdapter(private val listViewType: List<Int>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BBCSportAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    companion object {
        val ITEM_A = 1
        var ITEM_B = 2
    }


    var articleList: List<Article> = listOf()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val inflater =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return when (viewType) {
            ITEM_A -> ViewHolderItemA(inflater.inflate(R.layout.bbc_sport_list, null))

            else ->  {
                ViewHolderItemB(inflater.inflate(R.layout.bbc_sport_item, null))
            }

           }

        }




        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

            val viewType = articleList[position]
            when (viewType) {
                ITEM_A -> {
                    val viewHolderA = holder as ViewHolderItemA
                    Picasso.get().load(articleList[position].urlToImage)
                        .into(viewHolderA.topFlameImageView)
                }else ->  {
                    val viewHolderB = holder as ViewHolderItemB

                }
            }
        }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articleList.size
    }


//            holder.articleTitle.text = articleList[position].title
//                    holder . articleSourceName . text = articleList [position].source.name
//                    Picasso . get ().load(articleList.get(position).urlToImage).into(holder.image)
//
//                val input = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
//                val output = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
//                var d = Date()
//            try {
//                d = input.parse(articleList[5].publishedAt)
//            } catch (e: ParseException) {
//                try {
//                    val fallback = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
//                    fallback.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
//                    d = fallback.parse(articleList[5].publishedAt)
//                } catch (e2: ParseException) {
//                    // TODO handle error
//                    val formatted = output.format(d)
//                    val timelinePoint = LocalDateTime.parse(formatted)
//                    val now = LocalDateTime.now()
//
//                    var elapsedTime = Duration.between(timelinePoint, now)
//
//                    println(timelinePoint)
//                    println(now)
//                    elapsedTime.toMinutes()
//
//                    holder.articleTime.text = "${elapsedTime.toMinutes()}"
//                }
//            }
//        }

        fun setMovieListItems(articleList: List<Article>) {
            this.articleList = articleList
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        open inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!){}


        inner class ViewHolderItemA(itemView: View) : MyViewHolder(itemView) {
            val topFlameImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.topFlameImageView)
        }


        inner class ViewHolderItemB(itemView: View?) : MyViewHolder(itemView) {
            val image: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
            val articleTitle: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleTitle)
            val articleSourceName: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleSourceName)
            val imageCategory: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageCategory)
            val articleTime: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleTime)
        }

    }
```

I have followed this link https://github.com/CoderJava/Multiple-View-Type-RecyclerView-Kotlin-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ysn/multipleviewtypeexample/AdapterRecyclerView.kt

Answer (score 0):

In your onBindViewHolder articleList is list of artical but in your when statement you are comparing Article with an Int i.e. ITEM_A, which is wrong. Instead you should have some type in your article object and comparison is based on that type. Moreover you have not implemented getItemViewType() where you can make decision which view will be inflated. In your case viewType in parameter of oncreateViewHolder will always return 0 and else condition will be executed always and you will always have single type of view.

Comment: hi I want to fix issue on incompabitible types that was my question

Comment: inside when on bindviewholder. method override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val viewType = articleList[position]
        return when (viewType) {
            ITEM_A -> {
                val viewHolderA = holder as ViewHolderItemA
                Picasso.get().load(articleList[position].urlToImage)
                    .into(viewHolderA.topFlameImageView)
            }
            else -> {
                val viewHolderB = holder as ViewHolderItemB

            }
        }
    }

Comment: Read my new answer. You can not compare Article with Int

Comment: Show me your article class

Comment: Also how  are u distinguishing which artical should show ITEM_A type view and which article should Show ITEM_B